# How can I pass the yes flag to backfill in Google Composer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to do a backfill in Google Composer using a `gcloud composer` command but I am struggling to pass a `-y` or `--yes` for a corresponding `--reset_dagruns` argument.

The response I get is `airflow: error: unrecognized arguments: -y`.

Command:

```
gcloud composer environments run my_env --project my_project --location us-east1 backfill -- --reset_dagruns -y -s 2020-01-01 -e 2020-01-31 my_dag
```

How can I supply this argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone else has this issue, I was not able to find a way to pass in the argument using `gcloud composer`.

Instead I used `gcloud container clusters get-credentials` to do a `kubectl exec` to get a bash prompt on the airflow scheduler. From there I was able to use the native airflow command to move things along.

Answer (score 6):

**Before answering your specific question I have a suggestion**:
If your DAG (*my_dag*) already specifies the start & end date over which you need backfill, then just clear the status of runs you need backfilled/redone. The scheduler then picks them up again.

**For your question specifically**:
The AirFlow CLI documentation has unfortunately not proved directly usable with Google Cloud Composer, this is what works on Composer version 1.10.2

```
gcloud --project=my_project composer environments run my_env --location us-east1 backfill -- my_dag --reset_dagruns -s 2020-01-01 -e 2020-01-31
```

Note that this will hold on to your CLI session and will stop if you *ctrl-c* out, if your backfill is long you are better off defining a start date on the dag and setting `catchup=True`

Comment: Thanks so much for you answer and the advice. The dag runs in question had been deleted so there was no way to clear them. The backfill --reset_dagruns is what I needed. Eventually I used kubectl to run the airflow command (via bash) and that worked.

Comment: Great that you found a solution. There certainly are a few ways to trigger jobs in AirFlow (and composer).
On another note, I'm trying to build rep on SO, and would appreciate an "answer accepted" or upvote if you can. Another suggestion I'm seeing is to post your eventual solution as an answer to your own question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering